# ArrayFormula + multiple IMPORTRANGE + QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I want to import a few spreadsheets into one with some criteria, unfortunately if one of the spreadsheets doesn't return any data, the `ARRAYFORMULA` is asking for `ARRAY_LITERAL` instead of empty result.

What do I need to use in the `IFERROR` function so that `ARRAYFORMULA` appends nothing and is happy to continue?

This is what I have now:

```
={
   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("<spreadsheet>", "Range!B2:J"), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col9 WHERE Col1 <> '' AND Col5 >= 18 ");
   IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("<spreadsheet2>", "Range!B2:K"), "SELECT Col1, Col3, Col2, Col4, Col6, Col10 WHERE Col10 <> '' AND Col6 >= 18"), "")
}
```

I wrapped the second one in `IFERROR` but the empty string is not a valid `ARRAY_LITERAL`, so what can I do instead of it?

Full error:

> In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

I realised I could give it an empty row with the same number of columns like `I1:N2` but you never know if you might need to use these columns and then the query would need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using an empty [array](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en):

`=iferror(query(..., ...), {"", "", "", ..., ""} )`

Note:

- you select 6 columns, thus repeat "" six times.

**Edit**

by @Moseleyi.

> Makes sense, but of course, it still produces empty rows, and if I
>   wrap my ARRAYFORMULA in SORT, the empty rows will be shown first, but
>   when I use empty cells they won't, probably because they're actually
>   NULL. But I replaced empty strings with `IFERROR(1/0)` and it worked.

Comment: Makes sense, but of course it still produces empty rows, and if I wrap my `ARRAYFORMULA` in `SORT`, the empty rows will be shown first, but when I use empty cells they won't, probably because they're actually `NULL`. But I replaced empty strings with `IFERROR(1/0)` and it worked, so thank you!

Comment: Hi, @Moseleyi, great idea, thank you! I've edited the answer.